# Add background color to label in Extjs

Tags: extjs4

I want to add background color to label in EXTjs. Could anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use field's [labelStyle](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-labelStyle) config:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'email',
    fieldLabel: 'Email Address',
    labelStyle: 'background-color: #f00;'
}
```

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/42r3R/1/)

P.S. There is also [labelCssExtra](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-labelClsExtra) config which you can use. But I couldn't get it to work in ExtJS4.0.2a.

Answer (score 1):

Use the style config option :

```
{
    xtype: 'label',
    style: {
        background: 'red'
    }
}
```

**labelStyle** only works for using things like textfields